# Why did Fudge and the Weasleys come to the Leaky Cauldron in the PoA?

Tags: harry-potter

So, I was watching *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, in the beginning Harry goes at the Leaky Cauldron where he meets Cornelius Fudge and is later visited by Ron and Hermione.

Why were they there? Cornelius states that..

> Harry blowing up Aunt Marge

..wasn't a big deal. So why travel all the way to the Leaky Cauldron just to tell Harry everything is OK?

Also, Ron and Hermione would see Harry in Hogwarts anyway, so why come there?

Why bring all the Weasleys together?

Comment: I think they came to purchase their books and stuff IIRC not to tell harry its alright. Fudge however had come to ascertain that Harry was safe and had a place to stay where he could observe him for his own security

Comment: Not to mention, IIRC, Harry only met the Weasleys and Hermione during last days of his vacations, after spending some time at the inn alone

Comment: Did you delete your answer; Why; I was about to pick it as most helpful

Comment: I have undeleted it now. I just felt this question deserved an answer from the movies as mine was focused on books.

Comment: Well, the movies and books have a lot of differences but these events are almost the same in both. Not to mention, books are a higher source of canon.

Comment: @Aegon "An answer from the movies". Ha! That's rich.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Books

Fudge didn't come there to tell Harry everything is fine and dandy.

He had come to make sure that Harry was safe and had a safe place to stay, under his eye, in wake of:

> Sirius Black's escape from Azkaban.

He made Harry promise that he wouldn't stray far from the Alley:

> He could even go wherever he pleased, as long as it was in Diagon
> Alley, and as this long cobbled street was packed with the most
> fascinating wizarding shops in the world, Harry felt no desire to
> break his word to Fudge and stray back into the Muggle world.

The Weasleys and Hermione didn't arrive there until the end of the holidays:

> Harry woke on the last day of the holidays, thinking that he would at
> least meet Ron and Hermione tomorrow, on the Hogwarts Express. He got
> up, dressed, went for a last look at the Firebolt, and was just
> wondering where he'd have lunch, when someone yelled his name and he
> turned.
>
> "Harry! HARRY!"
>
> They were there, both of them, sitting outside Florean Fortescue's Ice
> Cream Parlor -- Ron looking incredibly freckly, Hermione very brown,
> both waving frantically at him.

They had in fact come to get to the Hogwarts Express and probably to purchase stuff for the school:

> "You can ask Dad yourself this evening. We're staying at the Leaky
> Cauldron tonight too! So you can come to King's Cross with us
> tomorrow! Hermione's there as well!"
>
> Hermione nodded, beaming. "Mum and Dad dropped me off this morning
> with all my Hogwarts things."

They knew however what happened with Aunt Marge:

> "I got all my school stuff last week," Harry explained. "And how come
> You knew I'm staying at the Leaky Cauldron?" "Dad," said Ron simply.
>
> Mr. Weasley, who worked at the Ministry of Magic, would of course have
> heard the whole story of what had happened to Aunt Marge.
>
> "Did you really blow up your aunt, Harry?" said Hermione in a very
> serious voice.

Quotes are from *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*.

#### Movie

Same is true for the movie more or less.

Fudge came for the same purpose in movie as well. Quoting the script:

> Harry: I don't understand.
>
> Fudge: Understand?
>
> Harry:I broke the law. Underage wizards can't use magic at home.
>
> Fudge: Come now. The Ministry doesn't send people to Azkaban...for
> blowing up their aunts. On the other hand, running away like that,
> given the state of things...was very, very irresponsible.
>
> Harry: "The state of things," sir?
>
> Fudge: We have a killer on the loose.
>
> Harry: Sirius Black, you mean? But what's he got to do with me?
>
> Fudge: Nothing, of course. You're safe. And that's what matters. And
> tomorrow you'll be on your way back to Hogwarts. These are your new
> schoolbooks. I took the liberty...of having them brought here. Now Tom
> will show you to your room. Oh, by the way, Harry. Whilst you're here,
> it would be best if you didn't... ...wander.

Harry and his friends however have the conversation about the Aunt Marge Episode on the train instead:

> Harry I didn't mean to blow her up. I just...I lost control.
>
> Ron: Brilliant.
>
> Hermione: Honestly, Ron, it's not funny. Harry was lucky not to be
> expelled.
>
> Harry: I was lucky not to be arrested.
>
> Ron: I still think it was brilliant.

Answer (score 8):

Fudge is lying.  Harry even calls him on it, and Fudge dodges the question.

Sirius has already escaped Azkaban at this point.  Fudge is up and about because the search is ongoing, and the coincidental disappearance of Harry Potter from his home is thought to be a prime opportunity for Sirius to snatch Harry.  He was a bit lucky that he happened to be where Harry was headed anyway, but that's the situation he's not telling Harry.

Ron and Hermionie simply show up at Diagon Alley for the usual reasons - books, sights, and it's cooler than home, and now Harry's there they have an excuse to hang.  The entire Weasley clan showing up and travelling to the train in a group is for everyone's (and Harry's) protection.